# How to enable Froala editor inside the wrapper div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

I'm trying to apply Froala editor on the button tag. But I want it to open using the wrapper div click. I've added the two demos on this question, please check and anyone is knowing the solutions, please help me.

Demo1:

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  new FroalaEditor('#editor', {
    events: {
      contentChanged: function () {
        console.log ('content changed....');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@3.0.5/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@3.0.5/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button id="editor">Change text</button>
</div>
```

This first snippet will open the buttontext in popup to edit on second click.

Demo2:

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
banner.on("click", function(){
 
  new FroalaEditor('#editor', {
    events: {
      contentChanged: function () {
        console.log ('content changed');
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@3.0.5/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@3.0.5/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button id="editor">Change color</button>
</div>
```

Here in the second demo, I've used the wrapper click event to initialize the froala editor.

**My Need**: On the click of **banner-message** div I want to open the froala editor popup to edit the button content.

If anyone can help me to resolve this issue it would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that you can try:

```
var test= new FroalaEditor('#editor', {
   events: {
   contentChanged: function () {
        console.log ('content changed');
      }
   }
});
```

also, a running Jsfiddle sample: [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/74Ljtz25/2/)